# Using Wkhtmltopdf and pdkit but copy text option not working once the PDF is generated

Tags: python, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using Wkhtmltopdf pdfkit with python but when the pdf is generated not able to copy the text once the pdf is generated on ubuntu.. Working fine on windows

options I am using with options -

Code I am using to generate the PDF. Below is the code I am using to generate the PDF

```
def generatePurchaseOrderPdf(datas,file_name,file_path,template_name, Quote, quote_vendor, ModelClass):
    options={
            'no-outline':None,
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'margin-top': '0.2in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.55in',
            'margin-right': '0.1in',
            'margin-left': '0.1in',
            'encoding': "utf-8",
            'footer-font-size': "8",
            'footer-spacing':8,
            'header-font-size':"8",
            'footer-right': "Page [page] of [topage]",
            'footer-center':"Madoverbuildings AI Private Ltd.",
            'footer-font-size': "7",
            'footer-spacing':5,
            'custom-header': [
                ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
            ],
            'no-outline': None
        }

    try:
        path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
        template = get_template(f"{template_name}.html")
        context = template.render(datas)
        exact_file_path = f'{settings.BASE_DIR}/{file_path}/{file_name}.pdf'
        if ENV == "LOCAL":
            config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
            pdfkit.from_string(
                context,exact_file_path ,   
                options= options,
                configuration=config            
            )
        else:
            pdfkit.from_string(
                context,exact_file_path ,   
                options= options  
            )
        return exact_file_path
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(e)
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        logger.warning(f'generatePurchaseOrderPdf errors {e, exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno} - {datetime.datetime.now()} ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to reply without seeing the actual code.
First thing to check is make sure that your Windows and Ubuntu run the same version of python as well as Wkhtmltopdf.

> when the pdf is generated not able to copy the text once the pdf is
> generated on ubuntu

What do you mean by copy the text? Do you want to use it in a variable? Please provide the relevant parts of your code so we can help you further. Also post any error message you may be getting when running on Ubuntu.

Comment: I am not getting any error message. When the PDF is generate you can copy the text from pdf that is not happening. The text written on PDF are treated as image means you cannot copty anything

Comment: Tell me if I got this correctly:
You can export the PDF on Ubuntu, but it doesn't have text embedded in it. The issue might lie with the environment and not the code. Have you tried opening the PDF file produced by Ubuntu on your Windows machine to confirm that the document produced is actually different?

Comment: Yes its different I am sharing a link you can check by copying the text
Check the pdf generated by ubuntu - https://shorturl.at/rwFO1

Pdf generated by windows - https://shorturl.at/mpqGJ

Pdf generated by windows we can copy the text but on pdf generated by ubuntu we cannot copy

Comment: Thank you for the links. Please check that you have the same version of pdfkit as well as python installed. That could explain the different behavior. If this doesn't fix your issue, we are going to need more than the options to understand where the issue may lie. Can you post a bigger portion of your code?

Comment: Yes versions are same for both I have updated the code in the question description please check

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a further look at it tomorrow but just to make sure, did you update path_wkhtmltopdf with the correct path for the Linux version?